# Angular filter contain

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a little problem with filtering. I make a few buttons:

```
<button ng-click="myFilter = {terms: advertising}">Advertising</button>
<button ng-click="myFilter = {terms: branding}">Branding</button>
<button ng-click="myFilter = {terms: packaging}">Packaging</button>
<button ng-click="myFilter = {terms: print}">Print</button>
```

And I've got array of course:

```
 $scope.selects = [
{terms: 'Advertising | Web',},
{terms: 'Branding | Packaging',},
{terms: 'Print | Video',},
{terms: 'Branding | Print',}
  ];
```

So as You can see I've got few terms in one key. I know that I can use search box to filter, and it'll works fine. But I've to use buttons for this.

This method:

```
<article class="select_single" dir-paginate="select in selects | itemsPerPage: pageSize | orderBy:sortorder | filter:myFilter" current-page="currentPage">
```

Works only if I use same string as It is in array, but I need to filter items with similar to them.

I tried to create hidden input, then send button id to input value, but then I need to do any change in this input to run filter.

Rest of code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" class="my-controller">


        <div id="loop">
            <article class="select_single" dir-paginate="select in selects | itemsPerPage: pageSize | orderBy:sortorder | filter:myFilter" current-page="currentPage">
                <img src="{{ select.img }}">
                <div class="overlay">
                    <div class="text">
                        <h3>{{ select.name }}</h3>
                        <p class="terms">{{ select.terms }} </p>
                        <a href="{{ select.link }}">More Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>       
            </article>
        </div>

        <div class="sort_handle">
            <div ng-controller="OtherController" class="other-controller pull-right">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <dir-pagination-controls boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/templates/pagination.tpl.html"></dir-pagination-controls>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So..

My question is how to filter this terms using part of array key string?

Grettings, W

Comment: It should be just as easy as `"...selects | filter: myFilter"`

Comment: Yea, It should be :) But it's not. I'm using: <article class="select_single" dir-paginate="select in selects | itemsPerPage: pageSize | orderBy:sortorder | filter:myFilter" current-page="currentPage"> but it works only with full string

Comment: what is `dir-paginate`?

Comment: You have extra commas in your `$scope.selects`. You wrote this `{terms: 'Advertising | Web',},` but you want to write `{terms: 'Advertising | Web'},`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly trivial since your filter is properly using the right structure that it meant to filter.

The bug is that your search filter should contain strings for `myFilter.terms` (notice the quotes):

```
<button ng-click="myFilter = {terms: 'advertising'}">Advertising</button>
<button ng-click="myFilter = {terms: 'branding'}">Branding</button>
<button ng-click="myFilter = {terms: 'packaging'}">Packaging</button>
<button ng-click="myFilter = {terms: 'print'}">Print</button>
```

Then the filtering is:

```
<div ng-repeat="select in selects | filter: myFilter">
   {{select}}
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. [Here's a working example](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/JorydP?editors=101)